# Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null : Angular and d3.select

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm building a series of d3 graphs within angular 5. I'm graphing the same d3 multiple times with different data each time, so I'm assigning a variable to the id. The problem is, the id is assigned at the same time that 'd3.select()' is looking for it, therefore it hasn't been assigned yet and I get error *Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null*

How can I assign the 'id' of my intended 'svg' a variable from the same data that I use to graph it? Right now it's all in an 'onInit' function in my component.

In my precipitation.component.ts:

```
this.input_id += this.data.id

var svg = d3.select("#"+this.input_id)
```

My html looks like:

```
<svg width="180" height="100"[attr.id]="input_id" > </svg>
```

The whole precipitation.component.ts for reference:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-precipitation',
 templateUrl: './precipitation.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./precipitation.component.css']
})

export class PrecipitationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() site1;

constructor(private _dataService: DataService, private http: Http) { }

date: Date;
dates: any;
value: Number;
eachobj: any;
data: any;
values: any;
average: any;
myClasses: any;
name: any;
input_id;

ngOnInit() {
  this.name = this.site1.name;

  var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")
  this.data = this.site1
  this.input_id = ""
  this.input_id += "precipitation"
  this.input_id += this.data.id

  this.dates = Object.keys(this.data.historical_data)

  this.values = Object.values(this.data.historical_data)
  this.values.forEach((obj, i) => obj.date = this.dates[i]);

  this.data = this.values

  var svg = d3.select("#"+this.input_id)


  // svg = svg.select("." + this.name)
  var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 0 },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  barPadding = 5,
  barWidth = (width / this.data.length);
  var last = this.data[0].date
   var first = this.data[(this.data.length) - 1].date


  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1)
   .domain(this.data.map(function (d) { return d['date']; }));
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0])
   .domain(<[Date, Date]>d3.extent(this.data, function (d) { return d['precipitation']; }));

  g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(this.data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d['date']); })
  .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d['precipitation']); })
  .attr("width", barWidth - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d['precipitation']); });

  var line = d3.line()
  .x(function (d) { return x(d['date']); })
  .y(function (d) { return y(d['precipitation']); });

  svg.append('g')
  .attr("class", "axis--x")
  .append("text")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("x", (width / 2) - 80)
  .attr("y", height + 40)
  .text(first)
  .style("font-size", "09")
  .style("font-family", "Roboto")
  .style('fill', '#5a5a5a');
  svg.append('g')
  .attr("class", "axis--x")
  .append("text")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("x", (width / 2) + 45)
  .attr("y", height + 40)
  .text(last)
  .style("font-size", "09")
  .style("font-family", "Roboto")
  .style('fill', '#5a5a5a');

  svg.append("path")
  .data(this.data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
 }


}
```

By the way I receive the data through the parent component:

```
<app-precipitation [site1]="site"></app-precipitation>
```

Comment: Did you try to put the code in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Frankly speaking, you've created a very big mess in your component class. Ideally the code should have been a part of a service instead.

Anyway, as metioned by @Niladri, you should be moving the code where you're trying to access the DOM in `ngAfterViewInit` as that's where the elements will be available.

Comment: @Niladri hm not yet! Do I assign the variable in oninit, then graph in ngAfterViewInit?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera you're right. This is a bit of a mess. But until now I did not know of the existence of ngAftervVewInit! Thanks, this helps me move forward.

Comment: @LaurenAH Ideally when the property binding is changed/assigned `OnChanges` lifecycle hook is called first, `ngOnInit` will be be called only after that,So you have access to the property in the `ngOnInit` event. You can put the D3 graph after the component view is initialized.in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Grab your data and assign it on the onInit, do your DOM element selection AfterViewInit (or afterviewchecked if you need updating after other content checks for subsequent updating)